# BindingSource Filter and querying

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I filtered my BindingSource and can notice the results great on a gridview control that is tied in... but when I iterate through manually, I am not getting expected results.  Here is the code:

```
    CollectorAlertsBindingSource.Filter = "CollectorAlert_Name='" & nameCA & "'"
    Me.CollectorAlertsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PWDS.CollectorAlerts)

    Dim CARows As DataRow

    For Each CARows In PWDS.CollectorAlerts.Rows
        txtCollectorAlertName.Text = CARows("CollectorAlert_Name").ToString
        txtTimedInterval.Text = CARows("CollectorAlert_TriggerInterval").ToString
    Next
```

I can tell when I step through the code that the ROWS.Count = 3.  There are a total of 3 rows in the table, but the filter should have filtered it down to 1.  I'm sure I am looking at this completely wrong, so I need a bit of help.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You filtered the BindingSource, but then you're not using it - you're pulling rows directly from the datatable.  When you apply a filter, the bs actually filters via its own DataView, (which is a layer that sits on top of the datatable. You can see this in the debugger as the 'syncroot' property of the bs.) The table itself still has all the rows within it.

Comment: I don't see any .DefaultView :(  Not on the CollectorAlerts Datatable .  When I try that I get the error:  'rows' is not a member of System.Data.Dataview

Comment: I tried iterating through the DefaultView using the DataRowView as well, but that produced the same results.

Comment: When I break and look at the DefaultView.Count I get 3 :)  Should I add a rowfilter on there too?  Or is that the better method?

Comment: ok, I answered my own question.. I needed to add a rowfilter to the defaultview.  Not sure why that was the right method, but it worked.  Thanks for your help!! Can you put that up in your answer so that I can mark as solved?

Comment: @cb seo I've edited and corrected my answer, and limited it to answering your question. (I don't think this was my best SO contribution tbh, tho it did contain the gist of the right answer.)